# jquery slideshow plugin making and testing

Tags: jquery, testing, plugins, slideshow

I want make my own jQuery plugin, like jCarousel. 
It works, but the problem when i leave the page and stay out for maybe 40 sec in Chrome and 1-2 min in Firefox it make's all img visible. It works fine in Opera. 
I use var e for current image and console it in the moment plugin must hide image.
When i leave the page e get attr style="opacity:0" (which must be used for fadeIn).
Plugin is on my hosting, here's the link: [changeImg](http://phil-bike.ru/changeimg.html)
Here's the code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.changeImg = function (options) {
        var def = {
            waitla: 5000,
        };
        var o = jQuery.extend(def, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var l = $('img', this).length;
            var i = 1;
            $('img:not(:first)', this).hide();
            $(this).prepend('<div id=changeImg-prev></div>');
            $(this).prepend('<div id=changeImg-next></div>');
            $(this).prepend('<span id=changeImg-count>' + i + '/' + l + '</span>');
            $(this).prepend('<span id=changeImg-play>STOP</span>');
            var e = $('img:first', this);
            var a = setTimeout(nextImg, o.waitla);
            var play_key = true;
            $('#changeImg-next').click(nextImg);
            $('#changeImg-prev').click(function () {
                e.hide();
                if (e.prev().is('img')) {
                    e = e.prev();
                    e.fadeIn('slow');
                    i--;
                } else {
                    $('#changeImg img:last').fadeIn('slow');
                    e = $('#changeImg img:last');
                    i = l;
                };
                $('#changeImg-count').text(i + '/' + l);
                $('#changeImg-thumbs img').css('opacity', '0.5');
                $('#changeImg-thumbs img[src*=' + i + ']').css('opacity', '1');
                if (play_key) {
                    clearTimeout(a);
                    a = setTimeout(nextImg, o.waitla);
                };
            });
            $('#changeImg-thumbs img:not(:first)').css('opacity', '0.5');
            $('#changeImg-play').click(function () {
                if (play_key) {
                    $(this).text('PLAY');
                    play_key = false;
                    clearTimeout(a);
                } else {
                    $(this).text('STOP');
                    play_key = true;
                    a = setTimeout(nextImg, o.waitla);
                };
            });
            $('#changeImg-thumbs img').hover(function () {
                if (e.attr('src') != $(this).attr('alt')) {
                    $(this).animate({
                        'opacity': '1'
                    });
                };
            },
            function () {
                if (e.attr('src') != $(this).attr('alt')) {
                    $(this).animate({
                        'opacity': '0.5'
                    });
                };
            }).click(function () {
                thumb = $(this).attr('alt');
                $('#changeImg-thumbs img').css('opacity', '0.5');
                $(this).css('opacity', '1');
                if (e.attr('src') != thumb) {
                    e.hide();
                    thumb = thumb.replace('images/', '').replace('.jpg', '');
                    e = $('#changeImg img[src*=' + thumb + ']');
                    e.fadeIn('slow');
                    i = $(this).attr('src');
                    i = i.replace('changeimg/thumb', '').replace('.jpg', '');
                };
                $('#changeImg-count').text(i + '/' + l);
                if (play_key) {
                    clearTimeout(a);
                    a = setTimeout(nextImg, o.waitla);
                };
            });


            function nextImg() {
                e.hide();
                console.log(e);
                if (e.next().is('img')) {
                    e = e.next();
                    e.fadeIn('slow');
                    i++;
                } else {
                    e = $('#changeImg img:first');
                    e.fadeIn('slow');
                    i = 1;
                };
                $('#changeImg-count').text(i + '/' + l);
                $('#changeImg-thumbs img').css({
                    'opacity': '0.5',
                });
                $('#changeImg-thumbs img[src*=' + i + ']').css('opacity', '1');
                if (play_key) {
                    clearTimeout(a);
                    a = setTimeout(nextImg, o.waitla);
                };
            };
        });
    };
})(jQuery)
```

i use tag 'alt' of thumbs image for change image by click.

wait for answer. thx .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it works, after download new version of jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to be hidden by default, do so with CSS, an THEN use your plugin to show them. Otherwise, you get a bit of "flicker" in the time it takes the JavaScript to be parsed.

Comment: Hi. I change it in the way you tell m, but the problem still the same. I put more info in description, try console var e, maybe it will help you get what the problem is.